# Solving a system of nonlinear ODEs (Lotka-Volterra equations)

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, nonlinear

I am trying to solve the following system of nonlinear ODEs (Lotka-Volterra equations: Predator-Prey Model, see:
http://greenteapress.com/matlab/PhysModMatlab.pdf
p. 108)

```
eq1 = R'[t] - r R[t] - alpha R[t] F[t];
eq2 = F'[t] - delta F[t] + beta R[t] F[t];
```

with the following set of parameters

```
r = 5/10; alpha = 1/100; delta = -5/10; beta = 1/100;
```

Initial conditions are `F[0] == 0` and `R[0] == 0` and the time interval of interest is `{t,0,50}`. I  use `NDSolve`.

```
NDSolve[
 eq1 == 0 && eq2 == 0 && R[0] == 80 && F[0] == 100, {R, F}, {t, 0, 
  50}]
```

I get an error message:

```
Error test failure at t == 47.273657697681124`; unable to continue.
```

and as an output two interpolating functions. I have solved the same initial problem in Octave making use of `ode45` function. Mathematica's interpolating solutions behavior does not match that obtained in Octave.

How can I ameliorate `NDSolve` performance (Mathematica version number: 11.3)?

Comment: Try `Method -> "Adams"` in `NDSolve`. And other methods.

Comment: You can try with, Quiet@NDSolve[
  eq1 == 0 && eq2 == 0 && R[0] == 80 && F[0] == 100, {R, F}, {t, 0, 
   50}]

Comment: As @Alan mentioned, please check your equations and parameter setups, e.g., with [Lotka-Volterra equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka–Volterra_equations).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not an LV system.  It looks like you lost track of the parameter signs.  Try this:

```
With[{r = 5/10, alpha = 1/100, delta = 5/10, beta = 1/100},
 eq1 = R'[t] == r R[t] - alpha R[t] F[t];
 eq2 = F'[t] == -delta F[t] + beta R[t] F[t];]
slv = NDSolve[
  eq1 && eq2 && R[0] == 80 && F[0] == 100, {R, F}, {t, 0, 50}]
Plot[Evaluate[{R[t], F[t]} /. slv], {t, 0, 30}]
```

Comment: Ooo. I am very naif:-)! Thanks a lot!